# Problems running Java Remote Debugger JDWP on iMac running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.7

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard, jdwp

I am building a Spring Roo app at work, and the remote debugger works there (27" iMac with a core 2 duo), but when I try to run maven in debug mode (mvnDebug) at home, (27" iMac with a core i5, also not working on my 11" MacBook Air 1.4GHz) the program freezes right after displaying "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000".

I do not believe this is a problem with Maven, or my application, because it works fine at work and it also freezes when I try to run Tomcat in debug mode, AND I have tried building a very basic Java application (which simply outputs a string to the console) and it also freezes. I believe it has something to do with Mac OS X or Java.

These are the arguments I'm using to run the debugger:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

I have tried many different ports to see if it was a problem with the port already being bound; this is not the case.

I tried re-installing JavaForMacOSX10.6Update4 from Apple's website, and it did not fix my problem.

These are the details on my Mac:

- Model Identifier:    iMac11,3 Processor
- Name:    Intel Core i5 Processor
- Speed:   2.8 GHz Number Of
- Processors:  1 Total Number Of
- Cores:   4 L2 Cache (per core):  256 KB
- L3 Cache:    8 MB Memory:    12 GB
- Mac OS X Version 10.6.7

Java details:

- java version "1.6.0_24" Java(TM) SE
- Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode)

Any help that you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a few days now, and been developing using "System.out.println" statements to figure out where I am in my code; it's horrible.

EDIT:

I appear to have permission problems which I cannot fix (Disk utility doesn't fix them, and sudo chmod doesn't seem to work either):

```
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/dt.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jce.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/jconsole.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/management-agent.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jce.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/management-agent.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/dt.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jce.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jconsole.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/management-agent.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
User differs on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib", should be 95, user is 0.
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/dt.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/jce.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/management-agent.jar", should be lrwxr-xr-x , they are -rwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/security/blacklist", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
User differs on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Libraries", should be 95, user is 0.
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle", should be drwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/deploy.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Resources/JavaPluginCocoa.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/libdeploy.jnilib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/deploy.jar", should be -rw-r--r-- , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
Permissions differ on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/libdeploy.jnilib", should be -rwxr-xr-x , they are lrwxr-xr-x .
```

For instance, when I fix:

```
User differs on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Libraries", should be 95, user is 0.
```

A new error shows up:

```
User differs on "System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Libraries", should be 0, user is 95.
```

Maybe this has to do with Java 6 Update 4???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Mac OSX 10.7 "Lion" and the JVM that comes with it, now it works.